# How to mass-assign protected attributes in a migration without changing the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations, mass-assignment

I'm using Rails 3.2

Is there a special command to assign a protected attribute in a migration without modifying the model with a "attr_accessible" statement.

I do have an attribute "pub_convention_id" that must stay protected in production mode.

However, I need to update its value during a migration.
That's why I'm geting this "famous message" : `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: pub_convention_id`

So I'm asking : is there a special statement to temporary deactivate the mass assignement protection (in a block for example) ?

This is the concerned part of my migration file :

```
ProjEncaissementCofin.all.each do |proj_encaissement_cofin|
  proj_encaissement_cofin.update_attributes! :pub_convention_id => 1
end
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proj_encaissement_cofin.pub_convention_id = 1
proj_encaissement_cofin.save!
```

or

```
proj_encaissement_cofin.assign_attributes({ pub_contention_id: 1 }, without_protection: true)
proj_encaissement_cofin.save!
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Is there however a way to deactivate mass-assignement protection temporarily ?